# Seeking COM-based Tree control with specific features

Tags: c#, com, tree, controls

For reasons I won't go into, I need a COM-based tree control with the following features:

- C# accessible
- Multi-node select
- Drag/drop nodes within the same (and possibly different) instances of the control within the same application
- 32 and 64-bit compatibility

I had nearly settled on Bennet-Tec's "TList" control, but found that it doesn't support 64-bit.

Any pointers?

*** Edit ***

I just found "SftTree/OCX 6.5" at...

http://www.softelvdm.com/Products/ActiveXControls/TreeControl.aspx

Downloading the demo now.  It sounds like just what I need, but if you know of other controls I should look at, please let me know.

*** /Edit ***

Comment: What will you display in the tree?  Shell namespace objects?

Comment: Just text-based data and/or icons.  That said, I'll need a way to link a tree node to my own underlying data structures, so if I get some of that for free, that's great.  Otherwise, I can probably manage that on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with the demo of SftTree, it appears to be exactly what I need.

http://www.softelvdm.com/Products/ActiveXControls/TreeControl.aspx